# matlab won't evaluate a condition

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements

Here's the code :

```
  clear;
channel = ddeinit('view','tagname');
temperature = ddereq(channel,'temperature');
poistka = 0;
time = 0;
kvas = 0;
ohrev= 1;

steam=300;
pressure=100;
steam2= 50;
tempom = 1;
pom = 0;
while time<3600
ventil = ddereq(channel,'ventil');    
pause(0.1);
time= time+1;
pom = pom+1;

if (kvas<=100)
kvas = kvas+1;
end;

if (kvas>=100 && temperature<95 && ohrev==1)

     temperature = temperature+1;
    tempom=0;

end;

if (temperature==95)
    ohrev=0;

end;

if (ohrev==0)  
temperature = temperature -0.1;
tempom = 1;

end;

if (temperature==70)
ohrev=1;

end;

    end;
```

I'm comunnicating with matlab and doing visualisation in intouch but I can't figure out why the variable `ohrev` won't became `1` when `temperature` reaches `70` value.
It goes up to the `95`, then goes down to `0` but it should stop at `70` and again go to `95` and so on but it doesn't work. Any advices? Thank you very much

Comment: your code is incomplete - variable temperature isn't started.

Comment: My guess: [don't perform exact matches with floating point numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab), especially when they're computed not assigned.

Comment: I run your code and when kvas becomes 100, variable temperature raises up to 70 and reaches it's value.

Comment: I edited it, please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where you check for the specific temperature of `70` degrees:

```
if (temperature==70)
   ohrev=1;
end;
```

The reason this fails has to do with fundamental issues regarding the representation of floating point numbers.  For example:

```
>> fprintf('%0.17e', 0.1)
1.00000000000000010e-01
```

Notice that in MATLAB (and most general-purpose languages) the floating point literal `0.1` is not represented exactly as a MATLAB floating point number.  There is a little extra in the 16th decimal place.  For that reason, once you start subtracting `0.1` from your integer temperature value:

```
if (ohrev==0)  
    temperature = temperature -0.1;
    tempom = 1;
end;
```

you will no longer have a number that is exactly an integer value.  Hence, the test `temperature == 70` can never be true.

The general solution is to *ALWAYS* check floating point numbers using a tolerance.  So instead of checking equality, do the following:

```
tolerance = 1e-6;  %% 0.000001; use whatever makes sense for your program
if abs(temperature - 70) < tolerance
    ohrev = 1;
end
```

This is a general issue when working with floating point numbers, so I strongly recommmend reading more on the topic if you are going to write scientific programs in MATLAB (or Python, or Java, etc.)

More: resources:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/57444-faq-why-is-0-3-0-2-0-1-not-equal-to-zero

[Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

Comment: Isn't your second name Genius? Thank you very much!
Well you know, it's my task, I didn't choose matlab...

Comment: :) well, like I mentioned, you'll have this problem in almost any language using the native tools, but it's easy to work around.  There are packages that allow for precision arithmetic computations, but they are usually much, much slower than using the builtin floating point capabilities.